# Attach a SQL DB on application start and detach on application shutdown

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have a specific request from the client to have DB attached to SQL Server only when application starts and to detached db when application is shutdown.

Application is Windows C# application (.NET Framework 4.7.1). I know that connection string can be used to attach, but I have no idea how to detach in a safe way.

Comment: call `connection.close()`

Comment: I need to detach db, not to close connection. And also I am using Linq to SQL to connect to DB.

Comment: Are you sure this is an architecturally sound decision in the first place? Just because the client wants it doesn't mean it's a good idea. What happens if your application crashes and it doesn't get detached?  Maybe a server-based database like SQL Server isn't the best choice. Sometimes you have to say "no" in order to serve the client best.

Comment: That said, you should have a better alternative ready to go when you do.

Comment: The best way to work with SQL is in a using statement. Are you using the correct terminology with the words attach and detach?   Do you mean connect and disconnect?
If it is connect and disconnect, leaving the connection open the enter time someone using the application is not a good idea. If you actually do mean attach and detach, those are sql commands, You can do this in .net but why?

Comment: Can you just run `EXEC sp_detach_db 'yourattacheddatabase', 'true'; ` before closing the connection? Also, I agree this seems a little odd though. I guess I can dream up some reasons you may want to do this, but for each one of those "maybe if they are trying to..." scenarios I can imagine a "but... why wouldn't you just do <this> instead"`

Comment: @KenL My guess is that the client wants to keep the database unavailable while the application isn't running. It's a "security policy smell."

Comment: Will a detached DB even get backed up (data and logs) if on a Maintenance Plan? If not, that's the best reason to bring back to the client.

Comment: I just assumed the client meant "open" and "close".  Is there a reason for the attach and detach?

Comment: To all you. I know that this is not a good idea, but client is insisting. He wants to have db in an external device and attach when application starts and detach when application is closed. He does not want to have db accessible in SQL server outside the direct usage  interval. My concern is that if I detach using sp_detach i need to kill open processes and it can have unpredictable impact.

Comment: JNevill supplied you with the way to do it as you are being asked.The real answer the problem is permissions. You can lock the database down in a number of ways.  Look up Application Roles. It is Microsoft's recommend way to prevent unauthorized access. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/application-roles?view=sql-server-2017